# Is there a way to code without a mouse?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editors, development

is there an efficient way to code without a mouse?
moving with the arrow on a text editor is too slow, but grabbing the mouse make me loose tim each time.

No cheating, no trackpad :p

Thanks.

ps : I'm not giving up my azerty layout

Comment: It depends on what tool your using. Depending it it different shortcuts will be available. You'll need to spend some time to actually read the documentation. Just as an example Ctrl+Arrow is often supported to skip whole words instead of individual letters.

Comment: What are coding with over there exactly. Are you coding the answer book to the kindergarten tests or what exactly? If that is the case you could code with a pen or pencil I suppose. I'm just guessing though based on the detail you provided so I draw this conclusion.

Answer (score 4):

Vim is amazing.

But --fair warning-- there is a learning curve. It comes with powerful search and editing commands that can leverage regex. No mouse required.

It comes with many linux distros and has been ported to Windows and OS X.

Answer (score 3):

Answer: **yes**.

You don't mention any specific text editor (nor OS) in your question, but it is apparent you don't have [vim](http://www.vim.org) in mind. I regularly use it over ssh to code on remote servers and I feel quite productive while hardly touching the mouse. I still use the mouse sometimes to select text that needs to be copied to the system clipboard (as opposed to vim's registers). By having a look at vim's [cheat sheet](http://www.viemu.com/a_vi_vim_graphical_cheat_sheet_tutorial.html) you'll find out there are so many ways to move efficiently within your file.

Examples:

```
3<Arrow Up> move up three lines
3W          move right three words, including punctuation
3G          go to the third line
fX          go to the next "X" character on the current line
0           go to the first column in the current line
^           go to the first non-blank character in the current line
y%          copy text up to the next matching parenthesis
cw          delete until the end of the word and start typing
C           delete until the end of the line and start typing
```

I agree with you: reaching for the mouse can slow you down. My recommendation is to try different code editors until you find the one that feels most comfortable, fits your style and allows you to work in the most productive way. I should mention many editors have a "vim-mode" that emulates several of vim's keybindings and functionalities.

This is probably not the place for yet another introduction to vim commands; however, since I see on this very same page warnings about vim being difficult to pick up, I'd like to say you actually need to know very little to wet your feet:

```
i           start typing code
<ESC>       when you're done typing code
<ESC>       when you accidentally pressed a key that had a weird effect
ZZ          save file and exit
:q!         quit without saving
```

Comment: On Windows, event without learning Vim, major IDE's like Visual Studio or Eclipse or editors like Notepad++ (and many others) allow to attain comparable productivity with standard keyboard shortcuts (e.g. Ctrl+S = save) so for Windows-only user, they are often much more intuitive to learn than Vim and *no mouse* is needed. But sure, many years ago they were not so mature so Vim was worth learning. My point is, for Windows-only users, Vim does not make significant difference today as it used to. But it can be still effective choice for users who are partially working in both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is hard to avoid the mouse 100%. Well, Vim is a good suggestion, but also have its learning curve, if you are not familiar with it.

As an alternative answer (on Windows) - and more to help avoiding to move your hand to the mouse:

Learn (you still need to) all the shortcuts for your IDE. But still you ocassionaly may need or want to use the mouse. Here I am using the num-pad for mouse-click (num key 5). Also you can navigavte the mouse with the other numbers (1-4 and 6-9) (but that is slow). It is called Mouse Keys, and is already part of Windows.

It is [activated this way](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14204/windows-7-use-mouse-keys-to-move-mouse-pointer):

- In control panel under Ease of Access
- Click Ease of Access Center
- Click Make the mouse easier to use
- Turn on [mouse keys](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14204/windows-7-use-mouse-keys-to-move-mouse-pointer)

Now, when you turn off the numpad (with num-lock), you can use it as mentioned. When num-pad is on, you can use the numpad as usual (entering numbers ect.).

I mainly use it for left-clicking the mouse button.
With ctrl+[number] you move the curser longer.

Answer (score 0):

#### On Windows, yes.

Whether you take IDE's like [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/), [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/ide/) or editors like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (no need to learn Vim), they have customizable key mappings so you can achieve all actions using the keyboard. If there is a missing mapping for something, the function is typically found in menu (or you can add shortcut to it).

Typical development scenarios where the mouse is needed are:

- **visual designers** like a form designer or a process designer. But this shouldn't slow you because at that time you will be holding mouse anyway :). Many times, objects in the designer can be moved also by keyboard, but it is more suitable for fine-tuning the location, because it takes long.
- obtaining some information from **tooltips** (hovering over variables during debugging etc.), but typically it can be obtained in different way, e.g. in Watches window.